# Variable's value doesn't change to the new one specified in the actionListener

Tags: java, variables

so I created a variable called savedName and then set the value of this to a new value in the action listener method. It prints the changed value in the action listener but ONLY in the action listener. It seems like once the action listener has taken place, the variable's value is changed back to "null" (the default value). The username_txt is a text field into which the user enters information. But as I stated, the value is only changed temporarily in the action Listener method it seems like and once the action listener has taken place, it changes back to the default value. I have bolded the statements for savedName.

```
public class LoginWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form LoginWindow
     */
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    **private String savedName;**
    public LoginWindow() {
        initComponents();
        conn = JavaConnect.ConnecrDb();
    }
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String user_sql = "select * from Users where Username=? and Password=? ";
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(user_sql);
        pst.setString(1, username_txt.getText());
        savedName = username_txt.getText();
        System.out.println(savedName);
        pst.setString(2, password_txt.getText());

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wecome!");
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
            this.dispose();

            UserMainWindow wind = new UserMainWindow();
            wind.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and/or Password is not correct");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    finally {
        try{
        rs.close(); 
        pst.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your action listener is a private method. Should that be?

Comment: Are you sure your `jButton2ActionPerformed` method has been called?

Comment: That action listener is a login button. I did System.out.println(savedName) in the actionListener and it prints the correct value. I need the savedName variable for another class and whenever I use savedName in the other class, it always uses the default value for savedName. The value is changed temporarily in the actionPerformed method but it is never saved.

Comment: It has to be getting called I am assuming because the user clicks on the login button, which is the actionPerformed method

Comment: If this method should be triggerd in the button click, it should be public and AFAIK you should register this method. Can you please share the code on how you have registered for the event?

Comment: can you post the other code where you have this object created? I am assuming that you are creating a new object everytime rather than calling the previous object... and unless you have encapsulation, savedName should be public if you are going to use it in an another class

Comment: I used a gui editor from netbeans to attach the action event. It automatically created the method name for me and it doesn't let me change the name of the method.

Comment: @Joseph118 which object? savedName? If so, it seems to work in the other class depending on which value it is changed to in this class. For example if I changed the default value of savedName to "test". Then it was getting passed successfully into the other class. Also I tried making it public String savedName and that made no difference either.

Comment: post the entire code inside the action listener as i cannot help you like this.... and yeah you are right! public or private will make no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting null from the other class is because you are creating a new object rather then passing the value into the other class. This can be done by putting a constructor inside your UserMainWindow class and accepting a String for the name. 
If you already have a constructor just accept String as a parameter and create a variable for the string and set it..

example code : (NOTE this is the UserMainWindow class)

```
private String savedName;
public UserMainWindow(String savedName){
  this.savedName = savedName;
}
```

now in the class you are creating this object, pass it the string like this: (and this is the class you are creating the userMainWindow class)

```
UserMainWindow wind = new UserMainWindow(savedName);
```

Now you should have savedName saved inside your other frame (user main window) while the other frame is discarded.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. But I am having non static variable cannot be referenced from static context error in my public static void main. I understand why its doing this, but is there a way around this?

Comment: In my public static void main (String args) I have UserMainWindow(savedName).setVisible(true). And that is giving me the error because savedName is static

Comment: Actually I got it working. I figure I should be able to change the variable savedName to static in my other class without it affecting other things. And it worked! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: you dont have to put this in your main, use it in the class you have provided here as you already have - UserMainWindow wind = new UserMainWindow(); wind.setVisible(true); inside this class loginWindow. anyway you should have issues with static unless you want to change the value

Comment: Oh yeah that works even better. I just keep forgetting simple solutions and keep trying to implement complex solutions. It works thanks!

Comment: This approach as a whole kinda messes up with the other classes. Some of the methods in UserMainWIndow didn't work properly since I passed a parameter to UserMainWindow.

Comment: give some scenario. :)

Comment: @user3754524 it should work without issues as you are only passing a string into the constructor. Now if you are calling this class using other classes, then that is another issue... you can pass an empty string if that so.

Comment: Well the UserMainWindow has buttons on the frame that serve different functions. For example one button is Hold Book which is supposed to put a book on hold ONLY if the book's availability is yes. But once I passed a parameter to UserMainWindow, the Hold Book button would hold any book, regardless of the book's availability

Comment: Then i don't think its an issue from passing a string... Its probably related to your sql query

Answer (score 0):

**Note :** I cant comment my thoughts so i just post it as an answer :) comment below for me to update my answer.

After the `jButton2ActionPerformed` what will happen? it will leave in `LoginWindow` class and go to another class or not ? if yes then the value of your String savedName will return to null.

> Instance variables are declared in a class, but outside a method. They
>   are also called member or field variables. When an object is allocated
>   in the heap, there is a slot in it for each instance variable value.
>   Therefore an instance variable is created when an object is created
>   and destroyed when the object is destroyed. Visible in all methods and
>   constructors of the defining class, should generally be declared
>   private, but may be given greater visibility. [click here.](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/data/variables/45local-inst-class.html)

Here is my suggestion .

**First :**

Create a Class that has a instance variable of `public static String savedName = "";`

E.g.

```
package com.sample.classes;
public class SampleClass {
    public static String savedName = "";
}
```

Then all the class that needed this Variable must extend it like

```
   public class Sample2 extends SampleClass{

      public void showUserName(){
        System.out.println(SampleClass.savedName);
      }

   }

public class Sample1 extends SampleClass{
    public void pressThisButton (String username){
        SampleClass.savedName = username;
    }

}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Sample1 press = new Sample1();
    // Populate the savedName variable 
    press.pressThisButton("My Name is Press");

    // access savedName variable.
    new Sample2().showUserName();

}
```

in this scenario you can still use the value of savedName even you already left on a certain class.

but im still not sure about this :), just comment if there's a correction TIA

Comment: So what do you suggest I do? The goal is to save the text in the textfield into a variable so I can use it in another class. Basically I am trying to save the username that the user enters into a variable so I can access that username's content from a database in another class

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this suggestion does''t work for me because I am already extending Frame